# Stop / correct a do while c#

Tags: c#

What i want to do is a code which accepts letters and just stops when a vowel is typed in console. My problem is that yes it does that, but it doesn't stop asking for more letters after the vowel is introduced.

Here is what i have:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char cha;
            
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert letter: ");
                cha = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (cha == 'a' | cha == 'e' | cha == 'i' | cha == 'o' | cha == 'u')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("We are sorry, ¡the program ends here!");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }

            } while (cha != 'a' | cha != 'e' | cha != 'i' | cha != 'o' | cha != 'u') ;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue a `break;` after the `Console.ReadLine();` to terminate the loop.

Comment: `|` is bitwise OR. `||` is logical OR.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp For boolean inputs, which is the case here, it's a logical non-short circuiting OR, not a bitwise OR.

Comment: @Servy. Thanks. I learned something today :) [logical-or-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-or-operator-)

Comment: Think more carefully about your while condition. Imagine you are the program deciding whether to loop or not.  I hand you an 'x'.  'x' is not  'a', so you continue the loop. I hand you an 'a'.  'a' is not 'e', so you continue the loop.  I hand you an 'e'.  'e' is not 'a', so you continue the loop.  You ALWAYS continue the loop.  Get in the habit of reasoning like this and you'll come to write correct programs. What is the condition you *really* want to hit to break the loop?  Can you describe it in words? Can you translate that intention into code?

Comment: More generally: get in the habit TODAY of reasoning about the code you *actually wrote*, not the code you *wanted to write*.  You're reasoning about the code as though you wrote "break the loop on the first vowel" but that's not the code you wrote at all.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: You might wonder what the benefit of a non-short-circuiting OR is. Remember, a conditional check is *code* and code takes *time*. It is often faster to do "evaluate left, evaluate right, or the results" than "evaluate left, check the result, produce the left as the result if it is true, otherwise conditionally evaluate right, produce the right as the result".  That condition check is surprisingly expensive because think about what the chip is doing. *It's doing branch prediction and branch prediction is frequently wrong*.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Moreover: if the left side is usually false then you don't save anything at all from the conditional evaluation of the right side; short circuit OR is more expensive than non-short-circuit OR if the right side is cheap and the left side is false most of the time.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks. That makes sense. I was thinking the use case would be something like: `if (someCondition | SomeFunctionThatNeedsToRunAnyway()`)...`. I guess if that were the case you would just reverse them. I hadn't considered the benefits you mentioned.

Comment: I note that experienced developers also fail to reason about the code they actually wrote; it's not just beginners. Case in point yesterday I spent about 20 minutes not understanding why my *obviously correct* code was crashing; I had written `if not x == y` when I intended to write `if x != y` and those are very different but my brain made me think I had written a simple equality check correctly when plainly I had not.  I didn't find the bug until I reminded myself to reason about the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1: The Actual bug:**

The actual bug in your program is:

```
while (cha != 'a' | cha != 'e' | cha != 'i' | cha != 'o' | cha != 'u') ;
```

If, for example, `cha` is `'a'`, then  `cha != 'a' | cha != 'e' | cha != 'i' | cha != 'o' | cha != 'u'` evaluates to `false|true|true|true|true`, which is true.  The corrected condition is:

```
while (cha != 'a' && cha != 'e' && cha != 'i' && cha != 'o' && cha != 'u') ;
```

---

**Part 2: Avoid duplicate conditions**

In general, I would recommend avoiding duplicated checks.  Your current code is checking for vowels twice, which is gives you two opportunities for bugs.  As an alternative implementation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char cha;
    
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Insert letter: ");
        cha = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (cha == 'a' | cha == 'e' | cha == 'i' | cha == 'o' | cha == 'u')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We are sorry, ¡the program ends here!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Here, we use `break` to exit the loop.

---

**Part 3: Don't use do-while for unconditional loops**

Most people prefer unconditional loops to use `while` rather than `do`-`while`, so we can further improve the loop:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert letter: ");
    char cha = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (cha == 'a' | cha == 'e' | cha == 'i' | cha == 'o' | cha == 'u')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We are sorry, ¡the program ends here!");
        Console.ReadLine();
        break;
    }
}
```

Notice that I was also able to move the `char` declaration inside the loop, since we no longer have to worry about scoping concerns.

---

**Part 4: Cleaning up our end condition**

At this point, we can go a step further and move the "the program ends here!" functionality out of the loop.  In general, you should try to avoid putting code into while loops if the code is going to run exactly once.  So, our new code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Insert letter: ");
        char cha = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (cha == 'a' | cha == 'e' | cha == 'i' | cha == 'o' | cha == 'u')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("We are sorry, ¡the program ends here!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

**Part 5: Other improvements**

I'll note that there are numerous little tweaks that might make this code a bit better.  I've avoided any such tweaks in favor of making the code conceptually similar to your existing code.  We might consider:

- Using `TryParse`, so that the code handles invalid input.
- Using `"aeiou".Contains` to avoid needing 5 equality checks.
- Also treat capital letters as vowels (AEIOU).

Answer (score -2):

You are hurting yourself a bit. Use a while loop instead.
This template,

```
int n = 5;
while (++n < 6) 
{
Console.WriteLine("Current value of n is {0}", n);
}
```

this way it will always check it before executing any input. Alternatively, you could use "break" but that is forcing it.

---

ideally, you should create a method/function that returns a bool isVowel,

```
 public static bool IsVowel(this char c)
 {
    long x = (long)(char.ToUpper(c)) - 64;
    if (x*x*x*x*x - 51*x*x*x*x + 914*x*x*x - 6894*x*x + 20205*x - 14175 == 
        0) 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
 }
```

or even directly as shown below.

```
char c = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
bool isVowel = "aeiouAEIOU".IndexOf(c) >= 0;
```

then you can easily set the true or false part of any loop you wish.

Comment: First of all, please do not teach beginners to program like that, doing simple checks as polynomials. Second, the math is wrong. Though LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I is in fact a vowel, I do not think you intended your method to return true for it, but it does. Don't get clever. Your second method for checking for vowel-ness is much better; it's readable, its extensible, its understandable, and its correct for the US-EN locale.

Comment: yes, I noticed that too. honestly, it depends on how the solution is going to be used. 

It is better to know possible options,

This is also why I gave the non-polynomial way to check for vowels.

I have seen more extensive ones, like: https://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/char/isvowel

Then again, I believe you are correct due to the constraints in the question.